# Postgres: Using WITH RECURSIVE to build list of item and their parents

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE category (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent INTEGER REFERENCES category(id) DEFERRABLE,
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE );
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
```

The rows I have added are:

```
INSERT INTO category VALUES (1, NULL, 'animal');
INSERT INTO category VALUES (2, 1, 'dog');
INSERT INTO category VALUES (3, 1, 'cat');
INSERT INTO category VALUES (4, 3, 'siamese');
INSERT INTO category VALUES (5, 3, 'persian');
INSERT INTO category VALUES (6, 7, 'scary1');
INSERT INTO category VALUES (7, 6, 'scary2');
```

I'm trying to figure out how to recursively query this using `WITH RECURSIVE` to get a result that looks as such:

```
   ids   |         names      
---------+------------------------
 {1}     | animal
 {2,1}   | dog, animal
 {3,1}   | cat, animal
 {4,3,1} | siamese, cat, animal
 {5,3,1} | persian, cat, animal
 {6,7}   | scary1, scary2
 {7,6}   | scary2, scary1
```

Where `ids` is an array containing each parent until the root, and where `names` is a string with each name separated by commas.
I also need to handle the paradox condition without hanging.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show sample data in the table as well.What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KaushikNayak I have added the row INSERT statements, and I'm not really sure how to approach it honestly.  I'm new to this type of query and I'm trying to make sense of the documentation but I'm kind of stuck understanding how I would do this.  I realize it's going to require some use of the array functions, but could use an example if somebody knows how to set this up properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of circular dependencies in your data you have to check whether `id` of the next referenced row does not exist already in the `ids` array. Use `distinct on (id)` in the final query and select rows with largest `ids` array.

```
with recursive categories as (
    select id, parent, array[id] as ids, name as names
    from category
union all
    select cs.id, c.parent, ids || c.id, concat(names, ', ', name)
    from categories cs
    join category c on cs.parent = c.id
    where c.id <> all(ids)
)
select distinct on (id) ids, names
from categories
order by id, cardinality(ids) desc;

   ids   |        names         
---------+----------------------
 {1}     | animal
 {2,1}   | dog, animal
 {3,1}   | cat, animal
 {4,3,1} | siamese, cat, animal
 {5,3,1} | persian, cat, animal
 {6,7}   | scary1, scary2
 {7,6}   | scary2, scary1
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Wow!  I'm taking it all in now, thank you very much for explaining this